# Drawing on map: get connected coordinates when editing

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When I edit a polygon I want to be able to get the connected coordinates of the one I am editing.

Example

[image]

When I edit number 1 (the one marked red) I want to get the coordinates of number 2, and number 3. Is there any way to do this?

My click event:

```
        google.maps.event.addListener(room, 'click', function(e){
                console.log(e);
            var thisRoom = this;
            this.setOptions({editable: true});

        });
```

Comment: What does your code look like so far?

Comment: It's a pretty large script so I added the click event. When I click on it the edit on the polygon activates so I can edit it. My goal is to make a right angle snap when you hold shift. For that I need that 2 connected coordinates so I can calculate the 90 degrees angle. (Google Mapmaker already has this but api v3 doesn't so I want to make my own)

Comment: Do not use undocumented properties of the Google Maps Javascript API v3 (`polygon[i].k+','+polygon[i].B`), they can and will change with every release (every 6 months).  Use the documented methods (`.lat()`, `.lng()`).

Comment: Ah okay thanks I editted it and it still works! I'm pretty new to google maps sorry about that. Any advice on my question though?

Comment: My comment was not intended to "fix" the issue", that will work until the API changes. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  You have the path of the polygon, the event listener is supposed to return a [PolyMouseEvent](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PolyMouseEvent), what issues are you having finding the information you are asking for?

Comment: Okay to ask my question again but very simply. When I edit a point of the polygon, how can I retrieve the coordinates of the point I just editted? (also took away the unnecessary code)

Answer (score 0):

By using this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(thisRoom.getPath(), 'set_at', function(e) {
  console.log(polygon[e-1]);
  console.log(polygon[e+1]);
});
```

I was able to get both coordinates of the connected points to the one I just edited.

Thanks for the advice anyway, I can finally simulate the 90 degree function :)